# Windows 7, how to reinstall from Windows.old, but without the disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

Recently I reinstalled Windows 7 (In control panel - Recovery) without the need for a disk. I've since realised that this was a bad idea - is there a way to reinstall Windows from the Windows.old file which was generated, but without using a Windows disk? I need to do this for two reasons: I don't have a Windows disk, and I don't have a disk reader.
I want to do this because my computer's acting quite weirdly - the screen refresh rate seems roughly 40Hz, even though it says that it's 60Hz. My mouse is acting very strange - the scrolling isn't working, I can't use the buttons on the side of it, and the actual cursor moves oddly.
Also when I try to play games, I get a relatively good FPS but with *very* frequent lag spikes.
I thought that this could be something to do with my drivers -I have the drivers I need on dvds, which I think would fix everything - the only problem is that my computer doesn't have a dvd reader. I tried an external reader but it didn't work (it does work on my laptop).
So I decided that it would be best to reinstall Windows from my Windows.old. I need to do this without the Windows disk.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be simpler to get the drivers across to that machine? Network/file sharing, or even email them to yourself. As it stands, this is very much an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I tried that, but when I run what running the disk would do, it did absolutely nothing. I also tried to install some drivers by telling windows to search in that folder, but still nothing.

Comment: Alternatively share the DVD drive on the other machine and access the files through the network.

Comment: This cannot be solved without a Windows 7 .ISO, so download one, see my previous answers on how to do that.  "So I decided that it would be best to reinstall Windows from my Windows.old. I need to do this without the Windows disk." - Windows.old **does not** contain the drivers from your old installation.

Comment: [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062)

Comment: @Ramhound "Windows.old does not contain the drivers from your old installation", really? Inside Windows.old there is a folder called system32, inside this something called drivers

Comment: @JacobGarby - Just download the .ISO and create a bootable flash drive.